# Blender geometry nodes stretching objects

Tags: modeling, particles, geometry, geometry-nodes, particle-nodes

i am new to blender and was trying to instance leaf (distribute leaves) but when I applied geometry nodes the leaf object gets stretched

[image]

Comment: I think your stem object is stretched by unapplied scales. Apply Scale on the stem object.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the leaf scale by selecting the leaf and hitting ctrl+A Scale.